# How to remove duplicate words from a string comparing to other string in SQL

Tags: t-sql, duplicates

I need to check string2 if there are words that I already have in string1 and remove those.

```
declare @Text1 nvarchar(500) = 'apple, orange, pear'
declare @Text2 nvarchar(500) = 'banana, apple'
```

The output should be 'banana'

**Edit: I just realized I made the question not properly.**
**So, this is right:**

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE (Ingredients nvarchar(500)) 

insert @Tab select 'apple, orange, pear' 

insert @Tab select 'banana, apple' 

insert @Tab select 'pear, mango'

declare @Ingredients nvarchar(4000) = ''

select @Ingredients = @Ingredients + value + ',' from @Tab cross apply STRING_SPLIT(Ingredients, ',')

SELECT @Ingredients
```

**current result:**
apple,orange,pear,banana,apple,pear,mango,

**expected result:**
apple,orange,pear,banana,mango,

Comment: Your data model is fairly broken as far as SQL goes.  You should instead be storing each fruit name in a separate row in a _table_.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: What database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @Text1 NVARCHAR(500)= 'apple, orange, pear';
DECLARE @Text2 NVARCHAR(500)= 'banana, apple, cucumber, pear';

--convert to xml for further split using nodes
declare @xmlText1 as xml =  convert(xml, Concat('<a>',replace(@Text1,',','</a><a>'),'</a>'))
declare @xmlText2 as xml =  convert(xml, Concat('<a>',replace(@Text2,',','</a><a>'),'</a>'))

--remove duplicates from @text2 that exist in @text1 
;with cte (val) as (
        select ', ' + value
        from (
            select ltrim(n.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)')) AS value 
            from  @xmlText2.nodes('a') as t(n)
            except
            select ltrim(n.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)')) AS value 
            from  @xmlText1.nodes('a') as t(n)
        ) as t 
        for xml path ('')
)
-- reassign @text2
select @Text2 = stuff(val,1,1,'') from cte

--output
select @Text2 as newText2
```

result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So if that is the case I would like to suggest you to create a function:

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE FUNCTION GetUniqueValues 
    (
        @LIST AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @POS INT
        DECLARE @LEN INT
        DECLARE @VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @POS = 0
        SET @LEN = 0

        DECLARE @RESULT NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

        WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @LIST, @POS + 1) > 0
        BEGIN

            SET @LEN = CHARINDEX(',', @LIST, @POS + 1) - @POS
            SET @VALUE = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@LIST, @POS, @LEN)))

            IF (CHARINDEX(@VALUE, @RESULT) = 0)
                BEGIN
                    IF (LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(@RESULT))) = 0)
                        BEGIN
                            SET @RESULT = @VALUE
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @RESULT = @RESULT + ', ' + @VALUE
                        END         
                END    
            SET @POS = CHARINDEX(',', @LIST, @POS + @LEN) +1        
        END

        RETURN @RESULT

    END
    GO
```

You can use this function like this based on you example:

```
SELECT dbo.GetUniqueValues(@Ingredients)
```

**Expected result**

apple, orange, pear, banana, mango

Comment: This one works, but I just realized I made the question not properly. Please see my question again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @Text1 NVARCHAR(500)= 'apple, orange, pear';
DECLARE @Text2 NVARCHAR(500)= 'banana, apple';
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM fn_split(@Text1, ',')
) a;
SELECT *
INTO #temp1
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM fn_split(@Text2, ',')
) b;
SELECT item
FROM #temp1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT item
    FROM #temp b
    WHERE a.item = b.item
);
```